# Cesium JS - Accessing primitive attributes without using id

Tags: javascript, cesiumjs

So essentially, I have a function that draws a colored rectangle at every globe coordinate point via coordinate and color arrays. (Frequency means new rectangle every x coordinates)

```
//Given an array of coordinates, respective colors, and level of detail,
//Draws heatmap on the globe
function DrawMapGivenArrays(CoordinateArray, Colors, frequency)
{
    var instances = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < CoordinateArray.length; i++)
    {
        var Cartesian1 = new Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegrees(CoordinateArray[i].lon, 
        CoordinateArray[i].lat);
        var Cartesian2 = new Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegrees(CoordinateArray[i].lon+frequency, 
        CoordinateArray[i].lat-frequency);
        var CartesianArray = Array();
        CartesianArray.push(Cartesian1);
        CartesianArray.push(Cartesian2);

        var newPrim = new Cesium.GeometryInstance
        ({
            geometry : new Cesium.RectangleGeometry
            ({
                rectangle : Cesium.Rectangle.fromCartesianArray(CartesianArray),
                vertexFormat: Cesium.PerInstanceColorAppearance.VERTEX_FORMAT
            }),
            attributes : 
            {
                color : Cesium.ColorGeometryInstanceAttribute.fromColor(Colors[i])
            },
            id: "Rectangle" + i,
        });

        instances.push(newPrim);
        numberOfRectangles++;
    }

    var primitive = new Cesium.Primitive
    ({
        releaseGeometryInstances : false,
        geometryInstances : instances,
        appearance : new Cesium.PerInstanceColorAppearance(),
    });

    scene.primitives._primitives[1] = primitive;
}
```

That works fine.. After I draw the map, I'm using this small function below to individually edit the color of one rectangle. (I call this for every rectangle to change all of them).

```
//Changes the color of a rectangle primitive given its unique id and a color value
function setPrimitiveRectangle(id, color)
{
    var CesiumColor = Cesium.ColorGeometryInstanceAttribute.toValue(color);
    scene.primitives._primitives[1].getGeometryInstanceAttributes(id).color = CesiumColor; //this line is 10x slower for every instance after it runs the 1st time
    //".getGeometryInstanceAttributes(id)" This specific phrase runs 10x slower after 1st instance
}
```

That works as well. But, for some reason, it has issues.

For example, when I re-color all of the rectangles the first time, it runs very fast. However, every time I re-fun that function again after the first time, it's 10x slower. I narrowed it down to the phrase that was giving me problems( ".getGeometryInstanceAttributes(id)" ).

I tried to circumvent calling the get function by modifying color values directly with this: (Where i is iterating over every rectangle).

```
            viewer.scene.primitives._primitives[1].geometryInstances[i].attributes.color.value[0] = 0;
            viewer.scene.primitives._primitives[1].geometryInstances[i].attributes.color.value[1] = 0;
            viewer.scene.primitives._primitives[1].geometryInstances[i].attributes.color.value[2] = 0;
            viewer.scene.primitives._primitives[1].geometryInstances[i].attributes.color.value[3] = 0;
```

Once I do this, I can check in chrome and see that the values located at those areas changed, however, the colors of the rectangles do not update.

I don't understand why  ".getGeometryInstanceAttributes(id)" runs 10x slower after it's called the first time, and why I cannot directly modify viewer.scene.primitives._primitives[1].geometryInstances[i].attributes.color.value[0].

Thanks

Comment: According to the cesium documentation, viewer.scene is readonly... I wonder if there is a way around that.